# Jooq 3.9.3 deletes custom generated java files after generate

Tags: java, jooq

This is an issue we face with migration from **jooq** version **3.4.1** to **3.9.3**.

We have a setup in which we extend `JavaGenerator` and override `generatePojo(TableDefinition tableDefinition)` to create some custom enum from data in database. This enum is created in a bit hackish way, using `PrintWriter`and writing the data into `FooEnum.java` file.

Something like this:

```
public class FooGenerator extends JavaGenerator {

    @Override
    protected void generatePojo(TableDefinition table) {
    super.generatePojo(table);
    // this works in jooq 3.4.1 but not in 3.9.3
    generateEnumClasses(table); // loads data and produces FooEnum.java with PrintWriter

    }
}
```

What happens is that the `FooEnum.java` gets generated and then deleted shortly afterwards. Funny enough, if i create **Foo**.**txt** file in the directory where enum should be created, this file survives `clean install`.

It seems that the enum is deleted after first (of two) generate goals:

```
jooq-codegen-maven:3.9.3:generate
```

Any ideas why is the enum getting deleted and how to keep the behavior from version 3.4.1 where it survives ?

This custom generator that we use to extend JavaGenerator is supplied to plugin with:

```
<groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
<artifactId>jooq-codegen-maven</artifactId>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <goals>
            <goal>generate</goal>
        </goals>
        <id>some id</id>
        <configuration>
            <generator>
                <name>org.jooq.util.FooGenerator</name>
             // ...
            </generator>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
</executions>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anybody else stumbles upon this, it seems that in newer jooq versions there is some cleanup code in

```
JavaGenerator {

    public final void generate(Database db) {
    // .... this deletes 'excess' java files
    log.info("Removing excess files");
    this.empty(this.getStrategy().getFileRoot(),this.scala?".scala":".java", this.files, this.directoriesNotForRemoval);
    this.directoriesNotForRemoval.clear();
    this.files.clear();
    }
}
```

which deletes excess .java files.

**Edit**

Here is a [link](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/5556) to github issue regarding this feature from Lukas comment.

Comment: Thanks for documenting this. Indeed, this was implemented in jOOQ 3.9. The rationale is listed here: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/5556. "Excess" in this context means that there may be artifacts from previous code generations that are no longer useful, because the underlying object (schema, table, etc.) has been removed. It's usually a good idea 1) not to put anything in the generated packages or 2) to register custom generated stuff in the lists you've mentioned, e.g. by using internal API like `JavaGenerator.newJavaWriter()` and `closeJavaWriter()`

Comment: Thank you for comment Lukas. Perhaps we should use Java writer for this as you say.

Comment: Yes, indeed. Your feedback is valuable input for our jOOQ 4.0 code generator re-design, though.